# When was the last mouse movement in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, mouse

Is there a command in Ubuntu to determine when the mouse was moved last? The screensaver clearly knows, but how can I access that data from the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Screensavers do their own polling for mouse movement (position change) or clicking. See the [XScreensaver FAQ number 10](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/faq.html#mouse-idle) which states exactly that behaviour. And as Jamie Zawinski — the author of XScreensaver states in this [bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=257092), the position is only checked every 5 seconds.

If you do not want to think about how to implement it yourself, you can use the C source code or the small apps given in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222606/detecting-keyboard-mouse-activity-in-linux), namely *[xprintidle](http://freecode.com/projects/xprintidle)*, *[xidle](http://www.freshports.org/x11/xidle/).*